# LWC - URL parameter value is shows Undefined

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Reading the url param through a lightning web component(Using LWC Components in Visualforce Pages).

URL:
https://sampleDEV/apex/Enrollment?enrollmentId=a082w000000YUQEfd

**Visualforce Page:**

```
 <apex:page >
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning" /> 
<script>

var enrollId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.enrollmentId}";
$Lightning.use("c:EnrollmentVf", function() {  //Aura app name
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:enrollment_5",
                               {EnrId : enrollId},
                               "lightning",
                               function(cmp) {
                                   // console.log("button was created" + enrollId);
                                   // do some stuff
                               }
                              );
});
</script>
```

**Aura app:**

```
<aura:application  access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >  
<aura:dependency resource="enrollment_5"/>
</aura:application>
```

**JS**

```
export default class Enrollment_5 extends LightningElement {
 @api EnrId;
// @api recordId = "a082w000000YUQEfd";
 @api recordId = this.EnrId;

 @wire(getParentdetails, { enrollmentName: "$recordId" })
 getContacts(response) {
  console.log("URL Param  ==>" + this.EnrId);
}
 }
```

When i print this `this.EnrId` value is getting `URL Param  ==>undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the class is first defined, `EnrId` is undefined.

This is when you are assigning it to `recordId` - which fires `getParentDetails`.

Which means, that your console.log will print out `undefined`.

Your options to fix include: pass `recordId` in directly:

```
 $Lightning.createComponent("c:enrollment_5",
                           {recordId : enrollId},
                           "lightning",
```

Or use a setter function so that when `EnrId` is set, it sets recordId (**bad** because it has a side effect).

```
_EnrId;
@api
set EnrId(value){
    this._EnrId = value
    this.recordId = value;
}
```

Or perhaps assign `EnrId` to `recordId` in the `connectedCallback()`
//I am unsure about this one, as I don't know when exactly this gets called.

```
   connectedCallback(){
       this.recordId = this.EnrId;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Caspar, It's Working now. Your're Awesome. :)

Comment: No worries! Which technique did you use?

Comment: The First one pass `recordId`